# 3D plane with image as textures do not show up in camera preview in Unity 3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, google-cardboard, 360-degrees

I'm using 360 degree photos and adding images as 3D planes as seen below: [image: Issue picture]

However, these planes do not show up in the camera preview in the Unity editor and when I use google cardboard.

How to solve this problem?
[image layers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LK1Bv.png)

Comment: Does your images are in the correct layer?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what's the correct layer, I screenshot a pic, is that what you mean?

Comment: [Layers documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Layers.html) We don't have enough informations to help you with just a screenshot... Their is a lot of parameters that can make that your camera do not display your images...